# Vue Custom Element failing to build standalone JS files in Dist

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I followed the directions for registering and using custom elements here:

https://alligator.io/vuejs/custom-elements/

I'm using the standard Webpack template for Vue.

When I run

```
npm run build
```

I expect to get a packaged web component file called element.js in the dist directory.  Nothing happens, though.  Does anyone know if there are any extra steps needed?  The documentation doesn't make this clear.

This produced the following files in my project:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <example myProp="I can pass props!"></example>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Example from './components/example.Vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Example
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

main.js

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import vueCustomElement from 'vue-custom-element'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(vueCustomElement);
/* eslint-disable no-new */

import Example from './components/Example.vue';

// Configure Vue to ignore the element name when defined outside of Vue.
Vue.config.ignoredElements = [
    'example-component'
];

// Enable the plugin
Vue.use(vueCustomElement);

// Register your component
Vue.customElement('example-component', Example, {
    // Additional Options: https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element#options
});


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

components/example.vue

```
<template>
  <p>Dynamic prop value: {{myProp}}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['myProp']
}
</script>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-custom-element": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

After including the script files for the custom element and vue libraries, my index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>example</title>
    <script src="vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vue-custom-element/dist/vue-custom-element.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: could you be a bit more specific? 1) what you mean by "nothing happens"? What did youz expect to happen, what did happen? did the console do nothing? Was nothing created in `/dist`? 2) What do you expect to receive at the end of the build process? The way that you have set it up now, It will not be a bundled component to inlcude in a page - it will be a bundled Vue application that *includes* one custom element, but doesn't use it. The vue-cli webpack template is meant to write aplications, not single components.

Comment: @LinusBorg  I expect `npm run build` to output `example.js` in `/dist`, in addition to what it normally does.  The doc at alligator.io clearly states that, given the files I included in my question, then "...after building to a standalone script, you should be able to add that script to any webpage and have it render example-component as expected."  I don't mean that the webpack build doesn't work at all.

Comment: Well,webpack doesn't know that you want a seperate `example.js` file. The webpack config says it should compile `main.js` into `/dist/app.js`, nothing else. That'S what I mean when I say the webpack template is set up to build an app, not a standalone component. I'll try and write up a small answer, but there's a lot to change if you want to do this, no idea if I succeed

Comment: @LinusBorg  I didn't realize that there was so much more involved than was included in the tutorial.  It's strange there weren't any pointers given about how one 'builds to a standalone script'.  It would be very helpful if you just point me in the right direction, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The docs and the alligator.io article don't explain it, but in order to work, a vue-custom-element still requires the Vue.js and `vue-custom-element` libraries.

So you have to use the `<script>` includes that webpack generates in the `index.html`.

---

Found a tutorial which mentions that:
http://vuetips.com/vue-web-components

> **This implementation requires Vue.js core files and the
>   vue-custom-element library to be included in your page.**

It also mentions https://github.com/kartsims/vue-customelement-bundler which is a template that builds everything into a single `.js` file.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but I tried to follow your advice and added the library paths to the index.html in script tags.  It still doesn't work.  I updated my question with my current index.html.  Please take a look.

Comment: @DavidJ. I meant the paths created by webpack in `/dist/index.html` there you can see `<script>`s for app, vendor and manifest. Those (and the files themselves in `/dist/static/js`) is what you have to use in your independent `index.html`.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand.  I copied that generated app, vendor, and manifest script includes from the index.html in `/dist` into the `index.html` in the project folder (this is what I understood from your reply), but that didn't do anything when running the build.  Could you possibly just tell me which file needs to be edited and what needs to be inserted?

Comment: @DavidJ. my bad, when you were talking about your index.html I understood you had another folder where you were testing the component without all the vue and webpack environment. You don't have to edit any files. | I'm talking about reusing, if you still want to build a single `.js` file try checking the bundler I have linked.

Comment: @yuri636  I followed the bundler instructions exactly and that's what lead me to ask my question.  It's incomplete.